# How to print number below in php?

Tags: php

I want to draw a pattern like this in php. I could not figure it out.

```
1   6    11
2   7    12
3   8    13
4   9    14
5   10   15
```

How can i make it?

I tried

```
 for($i=1;$i <= 5;$i++) {
    echo $i;
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    echo $i + 5;
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    echo $i + 10;
    echo "<br/>";
```

is this the best way to do.

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: You need a loop from 1 to 5 inclusive, print out that number, that number plus 5, and that number plus ten. Give that a try and, if you *still* have troubles, come back and ask another question.

Comment: Try mate, you can do it, just try !

Comment: previously i did like paxdiablo said but i do not thinks its good way.

Comment: Then write every thing in one line, why are you echoing that many times

Comment: @rahul_m i am just searching logic. not way of echoing.

Comment: "i do not thinks its good way"? When thirty-plus years of experience have you, young padawan, comment you may :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo i am just asking is that the best way. nothing else

Comment: Niroj, there was a smiley at the end of my comment, I was just joking, well half joking :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be nice to see what you tried, however:

```
echo '<pre>';
$i=0
do {
    echo ($i + 1).'  '.($i + 6).'  '.($i + 11).'
';
} while(++$i < 5);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your script here and it works:

http://phptester.net/

```
for($i=1;$i <= 5;$i++) {
    echo $i.'   '.($i + 5).'   '.($i + 10)."<br/>";
}
```

What error did you have? Maybe you forgot to close the loop with "}"?

Answer (score 1):

```
for($x=1; x<=5; x++){
 echo $x." ".$x+5." ".$x+10.+"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this... I have made in javascript. You can simply turn that code into php

```js
    var m = 1;
    var str='';
    for(var i=0;i < 5; i++ )
    {
     for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
     {
      str = str + parseInt(m+(j*5));
        str +='\t';
     }
    m=m+1;
    str = str+ '\n';
    }
    
    
    console.log(str)
```

Comment: hes looking for php. as u can see he is a beginner.

Comment: he has 620 reputation in SO dude... Turning this code into php isn't a big deal.. and definitely he's not a beginner

Comment: didn't see his reputation. thought he was a beginner